# FAB to open dialog to re-add any card eventually deleted in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm newbie to android programming and i would like to be helped on the issue i'm currently facing: basically i have a recycler view containing 4 cards, which can be deleted by swipe.

I also have a floating action button which purpose is to re-add the cards which have been eventually deleted.

It shows an alert dialog listing the items of the arraylist which refer to the cards that have been deleted.

The button works perfectly fine the first time it gets clicked.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40j2c.png) .  Here i've deleted the cards Monitor and Keyboard, and it actually showed in the alert dialog those two items.

However the problems come in the following clicks.

[Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mts8W.png) . The items just add up in the list of dialog (even if, as far as i know, running the instruction arraylist.add giving the same index should always overwrite the item).

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a solution to this problem.

Or even a completely new way to do this, if mine can't be fixed at all.

Please tell me if you need anything else to know.

Basically i just need a way to re-add a card of a recyclerview which has been eventually deleted. THANK YOU.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
private String[] button = {"choose os", "choose resolution", "choose type", "choose type"};
int initialSizeRows;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private ArrayList<String> title2 = new ArrayList<>();
boolean os=false, monitor=false, keyboard=false, mouse=false, first_time=true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(title,button);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    title.addAll(Arrays.asList("OS", "Monitor", "Keyboard", "Mouse"));
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    //adapter for arraylist item2 to be set in the alert dialog
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, title2);

    //fab
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        //fab onclicklistener
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (title.size() == 4) {
                //if no card has been deleted
                Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, "Nothing to add!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //check which card/s have been deleted and add them to the arraylist "title2"
                //the if(s) purposes is to always add the values in the correct indexes
                if (!title.contains("OS")) {
                    title2.add(0, " OS");
                    os = true;
                }
                if (!title.contains("Monitor")) {
                    if (os) title2.add(1, " Monitor");
                    else title2.add(0, " Monitor");
                    monitor = true;
                }
                if (!title.contains("Keyboard")) {
                    if (os && monitor) title2.add(2, " Keyboard");
                    else if (!os && !monitor) title2.add(0, " Keyboard");
                    else if (!os ^ !monitor) title2.add(1, " Keyboard");
                    keyboard = true;
                }
                if (!title.contains("Mouse")) {
                    if (os && monitor && keyboard) title2.add(3, " Mouse");
                    else if (!os && !monitor && !keyboard) title2.add(0, " Mouse");
                    else if (!os && (monitor ^ keyboard)) title2.add(1, " Mouse");
                    else if (!os && (monitor && keyboard)) title2.add(2, " Mouse");
                    else if (os && (!monitor && !keyboard)) title2.add(1, " Mouse");
                    else if (os && (monitor ^ keyboard)) title2.add(2, " Mouse");
                }

                //create alert dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                //set adapter with arraylist just populated above
                builder.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //to be done
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            title.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}}
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{
ArrayList<String> title;
String[] button;

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> title, String[] button){
    this.title = title;
    this.button = button;
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleTextView.setText(title.get(position));
    holder.buttonTextView.setText(button[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.size();
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView titleTextView, buttonTextView;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        buttonTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `title2.set(0, " OS");`when you want to replace the item. Add will add item everytime in the list. Set is used to replace the items in a List.

Comment: Thank you! needless to say it works. i'm checking with a bool if it is the first time the fab gets clicked. if true i use .add . Otherwise i use .set
The only problem now is that if another card gets deleted after the fab has already been clicked, clicking it again will make the app crash.
Do you know a way i could fix this? thank you

Comment: ok never mind i've fixed this. in case someone needs this: in the onSwiped  method i've added title2.clear() and i've set the bool variable first_time again to true so that the arraylist gets a reset and the program uses .add again. basically the alert dialog gets loaded again from scratch.